# Setting splash images for portrait and landscape mode in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, splash-screen

I have two images `Default-Portrait.png` and `Default-Landscape.png` in my resources folder. I want to set them as splash images for my application in the respective orientation modes. But when I run the application, I am not able to see any splash screen.

What I am possibly missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check your images again. Remove images from resources and add it again. Make sure clean all target remove build folder from your project, and Run it again it will work.

```
iPad Launch Image Orientations Filename | Dimensions

Default-Portrait.png                    | 768w x 1004h

Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png          | 768w x 1004h

Default-Landscape.png                   | 1024w x 748h

Default-LandscapeLeft.png               | 1024w x 748h

Default-LandscapeRight.png              | 1024w x 748h

Default.png                             | Not recommended
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XCode4 (and you'd better :p ), just drag these images to the appropriate image wells on your project's page. If they don't fit, it will warn you.