# iPad Landscape Mode - How To Add Two Splash Screen

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

I have successfully finished my app after months of coding. Now I'm trying to add the initial Splash Screen images to my app. How do i proceed? **I have two images:** one is the **company logo** and the other is the **app logo** (these splash screens are to hide the loading time). I have looked every where for an possible answer, but ended up with no solution. When i name a single pic **Default-Landscape.png** and run the Ipad App - The image is showing until the main view controller loads up, but I want the **first image to be displayed for 1 second and fade out to the second image** which will also be displayed for **1 second after which the main view controller appears**(the original application page).

I have checked various answers, but none seems to work - **[Xcode 4 and iPad2 splash screen issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575812/xcode-4-and-ipad2-splash-screen-issue)**
**[Setting splash images for portrait and landscape mode - IPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662230/setting-splash-images-for-portrait-and-landscape-mode-ipad)**
etc..

Here is my code for the same - AppDelegate.h

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSArray *docDir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath=[docDir objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"something.sqlite"];
    //databasePath1=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"something.sqlite"];

    NSString *bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"something" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *mngr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([mngr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {
        NSLog(@"File Exists");
    }
    else
    {    
        [mngr copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:databasePath error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"File Created");
    }

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

How should I proceed now? Should I create a new class like (splashScreen 1 and splashScreen 2) with uiImageView and change the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated: 30 May 2013**

**Appdelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "FBInteract.h"
#import "splashScreen1.h"


sqlite3 *dbHandler;
NSString *databasePath;
@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *naviObj;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *naviObj;

@end
```

**Appdelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    splashScreen1 *splashScreen1PageObj=[[splashScreen1 alloc]init];

    self.naviObj = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:splashScreen1PageObj];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.naviObj; 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

**splashScreen1.h** and **splashScreen2.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "splashScreen2.h"

@interface splashScreen1 : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imgObjSplashImage; //  IBOutlet UIImageView *objSplashImage; - in splashScreen2.h

}

-(void)hideSplash;

-(void)navigationToMain;

-(void)showSplash;

@end
```

**splashScreen1.m** and **splashScreen2.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.2 target:self selector:@selector(showSplash) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

    [imgObjSplashImage setAlpha:0]; //objSplashImage instead of imgObjSplashImage in splashScreen2

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)showSplash{


    [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.2];

    [imgObjSplashImage setAlpha:1]; //objSplashImage instead of imgObjSplashImage in splashScreen2

    [UIImageView commitAnimations];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.4 target:self selector:@selector(hideSplash) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

    -(void)hideSplash{


        [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

        [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.4];

        [imgObjSplashImage setAlpha:0]; //objSplashImage instead of imgObjSplashImage in splashScreen2

        [UIImageView commitAnimations];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(navigationToMain) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

    #pragma mark
#pragma mark - Navigation Coding

-(void)navigationToMain {

    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:Nil];

    ViewController *ViewControllerPageObj=[[ViewController alloc]init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewControllerPageObj animated:NO];

    [ViewControllerPageObj release];

    //[self presentViewController:ViewControllerPageObj animated:NO completion:Nil];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

}
```

The problem is ViewController(main ViewController) is not loading...I'm getting error saying **"message sent to deallocated instance" in viewDidLoad part of ViewController.m**

RootViewController -> splashScreen1 -> splashScreen2 is working fine(with all the animation fading in and out) but the final ViewController is not loading..

Comment: [iOS HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1) "Avoid displaying an About window or a splash screen. In general, try to avoid providing any type of startup experience that prevents people from using your app immediately."

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But my client says "he needs it". Even after explaining him about the same.

Comment: Adding some text check it out this one really helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

For this you definitely want another VC, lets call it StartViewController. Add there an imageView, block rotation and setTimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(moveOnAndChangeVC:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and if you develop NavigationControl app you should also change rootVC for example:

```
+(void)replaceRootVCWithVC:(id)vc {
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[sharedAppDelegate navigationController] viewControllers]];
    if(![viewControllers isEmpty])
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:vc];
    else
        [viewControllers addObject:vc];

    [[sharedAppDelegate navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers];
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should change in your appDelegate line with initializer:

```
self.viewController = [[[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

This should call your VC as a rootVC.

Then in StartViewController.m you should recognize device (this is a iPad only app, right? not universal) and orientation:

```
+(NSString*)recognizeDeviceAndOrientation {

    NSMutableString * returnString;
    if([StartViewController deviceInterfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||    [StartViewController deviceInterfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        returnString = @"Default-Landscape";
    } else {
        returnString = @"Default-Portrait";
    }

    if([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",returnString,@"@2x"];;
    else
        return returnString;
}

+(UIInterfaceOrientation)deviceInterfaceOrientation {
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
}
```

This will return you a string with DefaultScreen name with proper orientation. If you handling only one orientation forget about it.

Then in viewDidLoad you add imageView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[StartViewController recognizeDeviceAndOrientation]] autorelease];
   [imageView setFrame:self.frame];
   [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
   [self.view addSubview:imageView];

   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(moveOnAndChangeVC:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

This will call a timer and set imageView.

```
-(IBACtion)moveOnAndChangeVC:(id)sender {
   //if you using navigation app
   ViewController *vc = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

This will work. And then if you want to get rid of "back button" just change a rootView Controller like i said in the beginning. Do it in your ViewController class.

Comment: Ok I have added a new UIViewController and named it StartViewController. Added an uiImageView using xib. Now how do i proceed? Please can you explain the above in steps?

Comment: I created two viewController such as splashScreen1 and splashScreen2. Root View Controller calls splashScreen1 View Controller, thn it in turn calls splashScreen2,(working fine till now - splashImage1 - splashImage2 comes properly) but when my mainViewController is called, i get an error in viewDidLoad method( All functions accessing database when commented, such as [self getImagesFromDatabase]; the error points to viewWillAppear. I'm totally consufed right now.!!

Comment: hmm, maybe your VC is not be allocated properly. Check in your debugger what is `self.navigationController.topViewController` maybe is something wrong with your `replaceRootVCWithVC` call - can be too early/too late.

Comment: you should call it in your `moveOnAndChangeVC` method. Check also parameter you passing to `replaceRootVCWithVC:` method.

Comment: replaceRootVCWithVC: in appdelegate.m right? Like i said earlier, rootviewController is pointing to splashScreen1 View Controller, SplashScreen1 and SplashScreen2 are working properly, but when moving to main view controller im getting error (With NSZombie enabled - message sent to deallocated instanaces). When i somehow disable all error causing method is both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear- I'm getting my main view controller, but its not getting the details from database, such as images,text,color options etc.

Comment: No, you should replace rootVC from SplashScreen2 to MainViewController.

Comment: so I should just call the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

}
In splashScreen2? Can you tell me exactly how to do that?

Comment: I have updated my question with full possible code, please check that and let me know if you can find out the issue. Thanks in advance